# Must I duplicate ALL components to make a single installation project capable of producing both x64 and x86 packages?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

Instead of maintaining two installation projects for x86 and x64, I would like to use multiple Configurations and Release Flags to build both. I understand marking a component as x64 component prevents the installation from being run on 32-bit machines, however is this absolutely necessary for ALL components, at the Feature level, as described [here](http://www.installationdeveloper.com/1755/64-bit-installation-development-in-installshield-scenario-3/)? Ideally, I would only have to create x64 versions of components which matter, such as those with bitness-sensitive registry settings, COM and registry reflection options. I have over 500 components which would need to be duplicated..and this is just the first of the ten installers I need to maintain.

Is it safe to just make some 64-bit components marked as 64-bit components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to duplicate a component and make it 64-bit if something about it needs to be 64-bit. The two fundamental requirements are installation to a 64-bit file location, or installation to a 64-bit registry location. The former includes `C:\Program Files`, as 32-bit components go to `C:\Program Files (x86)` instead. The latter also applies to self-registration or COM table entries.

You do not have to use a 64-bit component to place an unregistered 64-bit file in a 32-bit location, and should not use a 64-bit component to deliver a 32-bit file to a 32-bit location. Note that if you've already released the 32-bit equivalent of a component, and are now making a 64-bit one, they each need to have different component codes. You won't feel the pain of breaking this rule if you block installation onto a machine with the other architecture, but you should still follow it.

Comment: What about components going to the GAC? Will they be added to the GAC as a 64-bit assembly if the 64-bit component is not set?

Comment: @Brundle That depends also on entries in the `MsiAssembly`/`MsiAssemblyName` tables, which in turn depend on the architecture of the file. If it has a different architecture, it's a different file, and it should have a different component. I haven't tested the interaction between `MsiAssemblyName` entries and `msidbComponentAttributes64bit`.